# Haskell: accessing lists from back

Tags: list, haskell, append

Today I started learning Haskell. I'm kind of new with functional languages, and I'm enjoying Haskell a lot.

However I've got a question about its design which is bugging me: from what I understood so far it looks like accessing an element to the back of a list is a lot more complicated that accessing the element to the front (something like `xs:x` where `xs::[a]` and `x::a` doesn't seem to be possible).

(From what I understood) it's possible to append a list to another one (`xs++[a]`), but it'll cost more at run time (it requires to traverse the whole list) and it cannot be used for pattern matching.

Why is Haskell missing such operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The list datatype

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

is defined like above.  There's only two patterns you can match: `[]` and `x : xs`, where `x` is the head and `xs` is the tail.

Prepending to a list

```
a = 1 : 2 : []
b = 0 : a
```

```
 (:) <-- b
 / \  
0  (:)  <-- a
   / \
  1  (:)
     / \
    2   []
```

simply adds a new cons cell and reuses the original list as the tail.

However, keep in mind that Haskell data structures are immutable.  Appending to the tail of a list

```
a = 1 : 2 : []
b = a ++ [3]
```

```
 (:) <-- a      (:) <-- b
 / \            / \
1  (:)         1  (:)
   / \            / \
  2   []         2  (:)
                    / \
                   3   []
```

requires building an entirely new list, because no part of the original structure can be reused.

In fact, consider

```
a = 0 : a
b = 0 : [ x+1 | x <- b ]
```

```
 (:) <-- a         (:) <-- b
 / \               / \
0  (:) <-- a      0  (:) <-- [ x+1 | x <- b ]
   / \               / \
  0  (:) <-- a      1  (:) <-- [ x+1 | x <- [ x+1 | x <- b ] ]
     ...               ...
```

How would you ever get the last element of the list, or append to the end?

There are other data structures such as [dequeue](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dequeue)s which are more suited for both front- and back-based access.

Comment: Right! I didn't consider that lists had to be immutable, and that for this reason they could be _extended_ only at the front OR at the back, but not both sides. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The list data type in Haskell is a linked list, so a lookup uses O(n) time. If you need frequent access to the back of a list you might want to take a look at [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html)
which has O(1) add to beginning and end.

To answer why Haskell uses this data structure as a "standard container" (like C and arrays), it's because Haskell is a pure functional language, and therefore has a preference to purely functional data structures (immutable and persistent.) For further reading look at [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional). To use non-functional data structures in Haskell would require it to be inside the `IO` or [`ST`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-ST.html) monad.

Comment: Your second sentence is what I was looking for. Together with @ephemient answer this made me understand why haskell lists have been designed like this. Thanks! `:-)`

Comment: I'm not sure its correct that Data.Sequence has similar complexity to a doubly linked list, as Data.Sequence has to do some balancing work when elements are added. A JoinList sometimes called a Monoidial list, doesn't do any balancing so should be more efficient for building. Don't use the JoinList on Hackage though, its quite badly written and needs an update (I'm the author) - in practice I'd expect Data.Sequence to perform better even on the things where a JoinList should win.

Comment: @Stephen, I agree so I changed it to be more specific about what running times that we are interested in here. I don't know what I was thinking about when I said that it was similar to doubly linked list because it is obviously not the case at all!

Answer (score 3):

It is the problem with pure List data structure, not with haskell itself. You can read [Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) paper to learn more about other pure data structures, that can have better performance on such operations

Comment: it depends. A list is a _built-in_ type, described by the Haskell language itself, isn't it? If so, haskell lists depend on the language design.

Comment: @peoro You keep pointing this out but what you're being told is basically "you're using the wrong tool", Haskell has tools that fill your needs but you don't seem interested.  Similar complaints would be "C arrays can't do O(1) cons" and "Python 'lists' aren't O(log(n)) lookup".  Obviously these complaints are dubious as it's just the developer misusing a particular data structure.

Comment: @TomMD, I don't "keep pointing this out", I commented this only once (to your and to this answer). I agree that if in C I want a list, arrays aren't good to my purposes. With my question (and with these comments) I didn't mean to say that Haskell lists are bad (just like C arrays are not bad), and I'm not complaining about it! I just wanted to know why they're designed this way; they're part of the Haskell language: thus lists design depends on haskell's design. To summarise, I don't need a different list as you and Yuras are suggesting, I just wanted to know why builtin lists work like this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be affraid to reverse() your list whenever you need. It's not uncommon to reverse a list before giving it to a recursive function, or to reverse the final result of a fold().

Answer (score 1):

These aren't issues with the language, just the List data type, which has some special syntax but is otherwise not exactly an "integral part of Haskell".  You have the same issue in C with singly linked lists but that's obviously not an issue of the C programming language.

If you want a doubly linked list with tail pointer then make such a data type and use that!  You might want to learn more data types (see the [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package, [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector), and the [dlist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist) package for examples).

Comment: a list is a _built-in_ type, described by the Haskell language itself, isn't it? If a list in Haskell is defined as it is it's because of the language design, just like C built-in types are defined by the language. A list in C is not part of the language, just like non-native Haskell datatypes are not part of the Haskell language.

Comment: @peoro the degree to which List is built in is purely syntactic.  Imagine if list were defined as `data List a = Nul | Cons a (List a)`.  The degree to which it's built in is orthogonal to your issue - if you want O(1) access to the tail then use a data structure that tracks the tail.

Comment: today I learnt how to declare new types and understood what you told me `:-)`