# Why are difference lists not an instance of foldable?

Tags: haskell, church-encoding, difference-lists

The [dlist package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/dlist/0.5/doc/html/Data-DList.html) contains the `DList` data type, which has lots of instances, but not `Foldable` or `Traversable`.  In my mind, these are two of the most "list-like" type classes.  Is there a performance reason that `DList` is not an instance of these classes?

Also, the package does implement `foldr` and `unfoldr`, but none of the other folding functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`DList a` is a newtype wrapper around `[a] -> [a]`, which has an `a` in a contravariant position, so it cannot implement `Foldable` or `Traversable`, or even `Functor` directly. The only way to implement them is to convert to and from regular lists (see the `foldr` implementation), which defeats the performance advantage of difference lists.

Comment: Further to Sjoerd's answer, a DList is only efficient for **building** - if you have built your list and want to process it, you should covert it with `toList` then process the regular list.

Comment: So why don't we simply define `fold (DL f) = fold (f [])`? We can forget about how `DList`s are implemented and simply view them as some representation of sequence of elements, and then implementing `Foldable` makes sense. Implementing `Functor` and `Traversable` in this way would probably have some pitfalls, but `Foldable` seems quite reasonable.

Comment: Yeah, `Foldable` might not be too bad, the package has `foldr` already and that's enough after all. I guess the reason it isn't implemented is because the last update was in 2009, when `Foldable` was not a well known type class yet.

Answer (score 23):

One alternative you should consider instead of `DList` is to use Church-encoded lists.  The idea is that you represent a list as an opaque value that knows how to execute a `foldr` over a list.  This requires using the `RankNTypes` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Prelude 
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Foldable (Foldable)
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import Data.Traversable (Traversable)
import qualified Data.Traversable as T

-- | Laws:
--
-- > runList xs cons nil == xs
-- > runList (fromList xs) f z == foldr f z xs
-- > foldr f z (toList xs) == runList xs f z
newtype ChurchList a = 
    ChurchList { runList :: forall r. (a -> r -> r) -> r -> r }

-- | Make a 'ChurchList' out of a regular list.
fromList :: [a] -> ChurchList a
fromList xs = ChurchList $ \k z -> foldr k z xs

-- | Turn a 'ChurchList' into a regular list.
toList :: ChurchList a -> [a]
toList xs = runList xs (:) []

-- | We can construct an empty 'ChurchList' without using a @[]@.
nil :: ChurchList a 
nil = ChurchList $ \_ z -> z

-- | The 'ChurchList' counterpart to '(:)'.  Unlike 'DList', whose
-- implementation uses the regular list type, 'ChurchList' doesn't
-- rely on it at all.
cons :: a -> ChurchList a -> ChurchList a
cons x xs = ChurchList $ \k z -> k x (runList xs k z)

-- | Append two 'ChurchList's.  This runs in O(1) time.  Note that
-- there is no need to materialize the lists as @[a]@.
append :: ChurchList a -> ChurchList a -> ChurchList a
append xs ys = ChurchList $ \k z -> runList xs k (runList ys k z)

-- | Map over a 'ChurchList'.  No need to materialize the list.
instance Functor ChurchList where
    fmap f xs = ChurchList $ \k z -> runList xs (\x xs' -> k (f x) xs') z

-- | The 'Foldable' instance is trivial, given the 'ChurchList' law.
instance Foldable ChurchList where
    foldr f z xs = runList xs f z

instance Traversable ChurchList where
    traverse f xs = runList xs step (pure nil)
        where step x rest = cons <$> f x <*> rest
```

The downside to this is that there is no efficient `tail` operation for a `ChurchList`—folding a `ChurchList` is cheap, but taking repeated tails is costly...

Comment: the `tail` of a `ChurchList` can be computed, lazily, in constant time.

Comment: Note that I said "taking repeated tails"; if you're just taking the tail once, the simple `churchTail = fromList . tail . toList` doesn't look too bad. But now consider what happens with `churchTail . churchTail`: you get a `ChurchList` backed by a `[]`-list that's constructed from a `ChurchList` backed by a `[]`-list. The heart of the problem is that a `ChurchList` and its `churchTail` don't share structure like a `[]`-list and its tail do. I don't believe that more sophisticated implementations of `churchTail` that don't use `toList`/`fromList` can avoid this either.

Comment: True, repeated `tails` are costly for other implementations as well. BTW I don't think that the `append` operation of a `ChurchList` is any better than that of a normal list, is it?

Comment: also, `singleton x = cons x nil = ChurchList $ \k z -> k x (runList nil k z) = ChurchList $ \k z -> k x z`. then, `snoc xs x = append xs $ singleton x = ChurchList $ \k z -> runList xs k (runList (singleton x) k z) = ChurchList $ \k z -> runList xs k (k x z)`. Also O(1). @is7s why? I think it is much more like the `append` for `DList` (i.e. function composition), not `[]`. Recently this was discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14942678/849891 and first, here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13879693/849891. I think it applies here as well - everything is O(1) until the first `toList`.

Comment: repeated tails is bad because functions are opaque. but maybe re-write rules can be employed to convert the inefficient `churchTail . churchTail = fromList . tail . toList . fromList . tail . toList` into the efficient `fromList . tail . tail . toList` by collapsing `toList . fromList` to `id`?

Comment: @WillNess No, it's not. A bunch of `append`s on a `ChurchList` will have the same problem when left-associatively composed.

Comment: @is7s could you give me a sample misbehaving expression please, to chew on?

Comment: @is7s https://gist.github.com/WillNess/5266509#file-churchlist-hs where am I wrong?

Comment: @WillNess for example the expression `(((a \`append\` b) \`append\` c) \`append\` d)` to compute the whole list, the list `a` will have to be traversed 3 times just as with normal lists. Difference lists were implemented mainly to solve this problem.

Comment: @is7s I disagree. I've updated the gist. the definition ``g = (((a `append` b) `append` c) `append` d)`` gets forced into WHNF on the first `runList g k z` and then rearranges itself into the right-nested `runList a k (runList b k (runList c k (runList d k z)))`, just like the func-compo chains of DList do. So `a` is run only once. Do you agree? (and if we don't name them, the unnamed thunks will get created instead, and forced).

Comment: @is7s thanks for the confirmation. :) This means, that this answer does provide a `Foldable` alternative to `DList`, without loosing any of its benefits. (!)

Comment: @WillNess has it been wrapped up in a package, with the rewrite rules?

Comment: @AlpMestanogullari I've no idea. :)