# Haskell. (Maybe a) vs a

Tags: haskell

```
belongs :: Eq(a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe a

belongs e (h:t) = if ( h == e) then Nothing else belongs e t
belongs e [] = Just e


nub :: Eq(a) => [a] -> [a]
nub l = nub' l [] 
    where 
        nub' [] new_list = new_list
        nub' (h:t) new_list = nub' t (new_list ++ [(belongs h new_list)])
```

Error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = Maybe a0
Expected type: [a0]
  Actual type: [Maybe a0]
In the second argument of `belongs', namely `new_list'
In the expression: (belongs h new_list)
In the second argument of `(++)', namely `[(belongs h new_list)]'
```

I understand error. But I don't know how to repair it. I don't understand why `Maybe Eq(a)` cannot be matched with `a`.  So how to repair it. I would like use Maybe here if is it possible.

Comment: you meant `new_list ++ Data.Maybe.maybeToList (belongs h new_list)`.

Comment: Not wanting to sound pedantic, but the way you write type class constraints is quite unidiomatic and I am sure, disturbing for many. You can just drop the () around a type variable, there is nothing to parenthesize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine what would happen on that line if you instantiated `a` as a concrete type, e.g. `Int`. `belongs` would give you back a `Maybe Int` which you would wrap to make a `[Maybe Int]` and immediately try to concatenate it with `new_list`, which because you passed to `belongs` must be a `[Int]`. This is what the compiler is telling you; you are simultaneously trying to use one value as two different types.

To fix this you can match on the result of `belongs` before wrapping it in a list and appending it. If it's `Just a` append the `a`. If it's `Nothing` don't append anything. Side note: appending elements to the back of a list is very inefficient*. You might want to add everything to the front and then reverse at the end.

You have one other problem. Your definition of `nub'` simultaneously treats `new_list` as of type `Maybe [a]` (by returning a `new_list` in one case) and as of type `[Maybe a]` (if you fix the above). **Edit**: Not anymore after your edit.

* As @WillNess points out, this is a bit of a fiction. Because of the pervasive laziness of Haskell, most operations that are commonly said to be "expensive" are not expensive at creation time, but only when elements are being used. A lot of quadratic time slow-downs vs optimal linear time operations occur because an incorrect order of associating operations causes the *retrieval* of an element to incur linear time cost. His answer that he [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938584/haskell-foldl-poor-performance-with/14942678#14942678) is a good explanation of this.

Comment: the matching and conditional appending that you describe can be nicely done with ``new_list ++ [a | Just a <- [belongs h new_list]]``. --- btw *appending* at the right is not inefficient; it's [the subsequent retrieval that's inefficient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14942678/849891). Each element will be retrieved in O(n) time.

Comment: Very good point. I was being lazy (pun not intended) and inaccurate. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a pair of functions; one claims to accept a list of any type (`[a]`) and return a list of the *same* type; the other takes a value of any type, a list of the same type, and returns a `Maybe` value of that same type.

A type and that type applied to `Maybe` are not the same type. But in the function that claims to be `[a] -> [a]`, you are trying to combine `[a]` and `[Maybe a]` and get an `[a]` as a result. That's just not going to work.

In order to end up with the claimed `[a] -> [a]` signature, it will be necessary to remove the `Maybe` from the result of the call to `belongs`, which introduces it. You can do this in one of two ways: Either change `belongs` to no longer use `Maybe`, or do some sort of case-analysis on the `Maybe` to extract the underlying value and then wrap it in a list.

If you look at how the types for list and `Maybe` are defined, you may see a similarity:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a

data [a] = [] | a :: [a]
```

Both are sum types that have a case that represents absence of value! So you can simply replace `Nothing` in `belongs` with `[]` and `Just e` with `[e]`. Now the result can be directly concatenated with `new_list` in the second clause of `nub'`.

Alternatively, you can use `belongs` as it is, and take advantage of the correspondence between `Maybe` and the 1-element list to write a helper function that maps `Nothing` to `[]` and `Just elem` to `[elem]`. Or, as @Will Ness has pointed out, you could use the existing function from `Data.Maybe` called `maybeToList` that does exactly this.