# Break an integer to a list of digits

Tags: haskell, digits

I am learning Haskell, and I am solving [problem 30 on project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=30).

```
digits n = if n<10 then [n] else (digits (quot n 10)) ++ [(mod n 10)]
isP30 n = (sum $ map (^5) $ digits n) == n
sum $ filter isP30 [10^5..10^6-1]
```

Is there a more readable way to implement the `digits` function ?

Comment: How about using an [unfold](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr)?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson , could you please elaborate ?

Comment: `unfoldr` generalizes a loop which produces a list element at every step. All you have to do is defining a function which, given the current loop "state", decides whether to stop producing list values (`Nothing`) or produce a value (`x`) and loop again with a new state (`s`) (done with `Just (x,s)`. For instance `unfoldr (\n -> if n == 10 then Nothing else Just(n,n+1)) 0` will produce `[0..9]`. You can use this to produce your digits backwards, and `reverse` them at the end.

Comment: Also keep in mind that appending as in `list ++ [x]` is inefficient, unlike prepending, since it needs to copy the whole list every time. It's much better to prepend elements and `reverse` the final list, so that only one copy is done.

Comment: @chi re: "copy ... every time": [not exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938584/haskell-foldl-poor-performance-with/14942678#14942678), i.e. nothing is copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @BenjaminHodgson's suggestion, you can write an `unfold` as

```
import Data.Tuple (swap)
import Data.List (unfoldr)

digits = unfoldr go
    where go 0 = Nothing
          go n = Just (swap $ n `divMod` 10)
```

However, due to how `unfoldr` works you will get the digits in reverse order here.  Another solution is to ditch this entirely and go with

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

digits = map digitToInt . show
```

My timings found it to be faster and use about 25% of the memory in an unoptimized GHCi session, it also doesn't reverse the order of the digits.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
digits n = fmap digitToInt $ show n
```

I forgot to mention that you need to import `digitToInt` from `Data.Char` first, as in @bheklilr's answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is always more readable to write code with guards, instead of `if-then-else`. All the extraneous parens are also distracting.

The standard transformation for the inefficient *appending-at-end* functions, like your

```
digits n | n < 10    = [n] 
         | otherwise = digits (quot n 10) ++ [mod n 10]
```

is to introduce an additional argument, where calling the old `digits n ++ xs` is the same as calling the new `go n xs`:

```
digits n = go n []   -- digits_old n ++ [] == go n []
   where
   go n next | n < 10    = n : next
             | otherwise = go (quot n 10) (mod n 10 : next)

--                            [a,b,c,...,x,y]         [z]
--                            [a,b,c,...,x]         [y,z]
```

Thus the digits being produced in the reversed order go one by one into the result list being built bottom-to-the-top in an accumulator parameter, resulting in the list  created in the correct order.

Comment: I was going to just say it's not *always* more readable with guards, but that's mostly because `MultiWayIf` wasn't originally part of Haskell. If it had been, we'd probably write something like `if | c -> te | else tf`, or possibly even `if | c -> te | else -> tf`.

Comment: @dfeuer the original McCarthy's syntax was quite nice. `{ a -> b ; c -> d ; e }`.

Comment: Also, the contention was that guards are always more readable than the literal `if-then-else`, really. :)