# TCO optimized Tower of Hanoi in Clojure

Tags: haskell, recursion, clojure, tail-recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I'm reading a [Introdution to Haskell](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html) course and they're introducing well known Tower of Hanoi problem as a homework for the first class. I was tempted and wrote a solution:

```
type Peg = String

type Move = (Peg, Peg)

hanoi :: Int -> Peg -> Peg -> Peg -> [Move]
hanoi n b a e
  | n == 1 = [(b, e)]
  | n > 1 = hanoi (n - 1) b e a ++ hanoi 1 b a e ++ hanoi (n - 1) a b e
  | otherwise = []
```

I've played with it a little and saw that it obviously using Tail Call Optimization since it works in constant memory.

Clojure is language that I work with most of the time and hence I was challenged to write a Clojure solution. Naive ones are discarded since I want to write it to use TCO:

```
(defn hanoi-non-optimized
  [n b a e]
  (cond
    (= n 1) [[b e]]
    (> n 1) (concat (hanoi-non-optimized (dec n) b e a)
                    (hanoi-non-optimized 1 b a e)
                    (hanoi-non-optimized (dec n) a b e))
    :else   []))
```

Well, Clojure is JVM hosted and thus don't have TCO by default and one should use `recur` to get it (I know the story...). In the other hand, `recur` imposes some syntactic constraints since it have to be last expression - have to be the tail. I feel a bit bad because I still can't write a solution that is short/expressive as that one in Haskell and use TCO at the same time.

Is there a simple solution for this which I can't see at the moment?

I have a great respect for both languages and already know that this is rather problem with my approach than with Clojure itself.

Answer (score 7):

No, the Haskell code isn't tail-recursive. It is *guarded*-recursive, with recursion guarded by a lazy data constructor, `:` (to which the `++` calls are ultimately transformed), where because of the laziness only one part of the recursion call tree (`a ++ b ++ c`) is explored in its turn, so the stack's depth never exceeds *n*, the number of disks. Which is very small, like 7 or 8.

So Haskell code explores `a`, putting the `c` part aside. Your Clojure code on the other hand calculates the two parts (`a` and `c`, as `b` doesn't count) *before* concatenating them, so is double recursive, i.e. computationally heavy.

What you're looking for is not TCO, but TRMCO -- [tail recursion *modulo cons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) optimization, -- i.e. building the list in a top-down manner from inside a loop with a simulated stack. Clojure is especially well-suited for this, with its tail-appending `conj` (right?) instead of Lisp's and Haskell's head-prepending `cons`.

Or just print the moves instead of building the list of all of them.

*edit:* actually, TRMCO means we're allowed to reuse the call frame if we maintain the "continuation stack" ourselves, so the stack depth becomes exactly *1*. Haskell in all likelihood builds a left-deepening tree of nested `++` thunk nodes in this case, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938584/haskell-foldl-poor-performance-with/14942678#14942678), but in Clojure we're allowed to rearrange it into the right-nested *list* ourselves, when we maintain our own stack of *to-do-next* invocation descriptions (for the `b` and `c` parts of the `a ++ b ++ c` expression).

Comment: Thank you for the references. But still, when I compile Haskell function with `ghc-8.0.1` and run it with much more disks, like 9999 it never exceeds the memory. Actually, processor load acting weird but memory is constant and no stack overflow happens. As I understand, you say that it should cause stack overflow for larger `n`s?

Comment: my understanding is, for `n` disks the recursion depth will be `n` as well. I expect 10000 isn't too much. Are you running the standalone executable with `+RTS -s` switch, for "stats"? There's also fuller profiling options, you must be able to find more about it on SO.

Comment: Can we see your Clojure TRMCO version?

Comment: @Thumbnail this would have to be an explicit loop with simulated stack, *implementing by hand* what a TRMCO-able compiler would produce. I'll try to cook something up later.

Comment: Don Knuth may have anticipated this in [Structured Programming with Goto Statements](http://sbel.wisc.edu/Courses/ME964/Literature/knuthProgramming1974.pdf) in 1974. Look at example 6 starting on p20/journal-page 280.

Comment: @Thumbnail thanks a lot for the link! Looks very interesting.