# Understanding the concept of difference lists

Tags: haskell, optimization, difference-lists

While I was reading chapter 13 from `Real World Haskell` i came upon the concept of `Difference Lists`.
The author says that in an imperative language if we want to append an element to a list, the cost would be `O(1)` since we would keep a pointer to the last element.
However in Haskell, we have `immutable` objects so we would need every time to traverse the list and append the element at the end, thus `0(n)`.

Instead of `[1,2,3]++[4]++[5]` 

we could use partial application: `(++4).(++5)  [1,2,3]`.

I do not understand how is this more efficient since:
- when i do `(++[5]) [1,2,3]` it would still be `O(n)` and then another `0(n)` for `(++4)`

**Quote**

```
There are two very interesting things about this approach. The first is that the cost of a partial application is constant, so the cost of many partial applications is linear. The second is that when we finally provide a [] value to
unlock the final list from its chain of partial applications, application 
proceeds from right to left. This keeps the left operand of (++) small, and so 
the overall cost of all of these appends is linear, not quadratic
```

I understand that this approach would be eager, so instead of keeping thunks of `yet to be applied methods` we keep the left operand `small` as the author says, but .... we still perform a traverse on each append.

Given a list: `[1...100]` and wanting to append `1,2` i would still traverse it `2` times since I would :

1. `f(f([1..100]))= f([1..100,1])` - traversed 1 time and appended `1`
2. `[1..100,1,2]` -traversed the second time to append `2`

Can someone illuminate me on how is this more efficient in time complexity? (because`space`-complexity is due to no more `thunks`, like `foldl'`)

---

**P.S**

I am aware of the canonical answer and I have also read [this chapter](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl) which I found very helpful.
I know that you can achieve `O(1)` complexity by appending to the left using `:`, but it wouldn't be similar to `++`.

If i use `f=(:)` on `a= [1,2,3]`  :
`(f 4 . f 5) $ a` 
I could say that i had `0(1)` efficiency on each append since i always appended on the to the left , but i would not get `[1,2,3,4,5]` , i would get `[5,4,1,2,3]` , so how  is in this case a `difference list` more efficient for the unitary operation of appending one element ?

Comment: see the [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879260/why-are-difference-lists-more-efficient-than-regular-concatenation/13879693#13879693), in general.

Comment: Only `(x :)` and `(xs ++)` are allowed in a difference list. (Note that the arguments are on the left.) Difference lists are efficient because they force every operation into a prepend.

Comment: Then what is the difference between a `difference list` and `foldl '` ? Doesn't `foldl '`  append the new value to the `buffer` at every iteration ,thus saving us from `thunks`?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938584/haskell-foldl-poor-performance-with/14942678#14942678 about the foldl (disclaimer: the answer is by me). `foldl' (++)` builds the left-leaning chain of `((([1]++[2])++[3])++[4])++[5]`.

Comment: to your new question, `(f 4 . f 5) $ a = ((: 4) . (: 5)) [1,2,3] = 4:5:[1,2,3]`. if you meant `((++ [4]) . (++ [5])) [1,2,3] = (++ [4]) ([1,2,3]++[5]) =  ([1,2,3]++[5])++[4]` then it again builds a left-leaning chain, i.e. is no good (quadratic). IOW, what exactly is not clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be more careful with times, i.e. *when* this or that thing is happening.

Instead of starting with a list `[1,2,3]`, with different lists we start with

```
f1 = ([1,2,3] ++)
```

Then to "add" 4, 5, to the end of the growing *difference* list, we have

```
f2 = f1 . ([4] ++)
f3 = f2 . ([5] ++)
```

Each such addition *into the end* of the growing difference list is *O(1)*.

When we're finally done building it, we convert it into a "normal" list by application

```
xs = f3 []    -- or f3 [6..10] or whatever
```

Then, carefully, we get

```
xs = ((([1,2,3] ++) . ([4] ++)) . ([5] ++)) []
   =  (([1,2,3] ++) . ([4] ++)) ( ([5] ++)  [] )
   =   ([1,2,3] ++) ( ([4] ++)  ( ([5] ++)  [] ))
   =     1:2:3:     (   4  :    (   5  :    [] ))
```

by the definition of `(++)`.

A canonical answer: [Why are difference lists more efficient than regular concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879260/why-are-difference-lists-more-efficient-than-regular-concatenation/13879693#13879693)

---

Even `a1 = (++ [4]) [1..]` *by itself* is an *O(1)* operation, as is `a2 = (++ [5]) a1` and `a3 = (++ [6]) a2`, because Haskell is lazy, and thunk creation is *O(1)*.

It's only when we access the final result, that the overall operation becomes quadratic because accessing the `++` structure doesn't rearrange it -- it remains left-nested, so *quadratic* on repeated access from the top.

The conversion to normal list by application of left-nested `.` structure to `[]` rearranges that structure internally into the right-nested `$` structure, as is explained in the canonical answer, so repeated access to such structure from the top is linear.

So the difference is between `((++ [5]) . (++ [4])) [1,2,3]` (bad) and `((([1,2,3] ++) . ([4] ++)) . ([5] ++)) []` (good). Building the function chain `((++ [4]) . (++ [5]))` in itself is linear, yes, but it creates a structure that is quadratic to access in full.

But `((([1,2,3] ++) . ([5] ++)) . ([4] ++)) []` becomes `([1,2,3] ++) (([5] ++) (([4] ++) []))`.